# Serialize a form which is generated by ajax, using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with checkboxes and it is generated using ajax and jquery UI tabs. I am submitting the form with post when someone clicks on a button. It works for the first tab loaded with ajax, but clicking on other tabs and then trying to submit the form, the data from the form is empty. So the serialize function does not work after changing tabs because it thinks the form is empty.

```
    // Bulk action Delegate
$("body").delegate(".bulk_action_btn", "click", function(){
    var data = $("#ActionAddForm").serialize();
    var action = $(this).attr('title');
    var currentTab = $( "#asst_tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );


    $('.asst_list2').fadeOut();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $html->url("/admin/actions/perform/") ?>"+currentTab + '/' + action,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('.asst_list2').html(html);
            $('.asst_list2').fadeIn(100);
            // $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked",false);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the relative html markup, the actual markup is much longer.

```
<div class="asst_action_bar">
<div class="action_group">
<p>Bulk Actions</p>
    <input value="Follow" class="bulk_action_btn" title="Follow" type="button">
    <input value="Unfollow" class="bulk_action_btn" title="Unfollow" type="button">
</div>
<form action="/admin/actions/add" method="post" id="ActionAddForm">
<fieldset style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></fieldset>
<!-- Loaded with ajax -->
<div class="input checkbox"><input name="data[Assignment][1580]" id="Assignment1580_" value="0" type="hidden"><input name="data[Assignment][1580]" value="1" id="Assignment1580" type="checkbox"></div>         <div id="1580">
<p><a href="javascript:" class="star"><img src="/img/top/followmestar-on.gif" alt="" height="40" width="40"></a></p>
</div>
<div class="input checkbox"><input name="data[Assignment][1580]" id="Assignment1580_" value="0" type="hidden"><input name="data[Assignment][1580]" value="1" id="Assignment1580" type="checkbox"></div>         <div id="1580">
<p><a href="javascript:" class="star"><img src="/img/top/followmestar-on.gif" alt="" height="40" width="40"></a></p>
</div>
<div class="input checkbox"><input name="data[Assignment][1580]" id="Assignment1580_" value="0" type="hidden"><input name="data[Assignment][1580]" value="1" id="Assignment1580" type="checkbox"></div>         <div id="1580">
<p><a href="javascript:" class="star"><img src="/img/top/followmestar-on.gif" alt="" height="40" width="40"></a></p>
</div>
<!-- Loaded with ajax end -->
</form>
```

I think the reason it doesn't work is that I am using the "#ActionAddForm" selector (the id of the form), which is probably not loaded after changing tabs. I am using cakePHP on the backend if that helps. I am using the jquery delegate method because it didn't work the form with the checkboxes is loaded with ajax.

Comment: This is hard to answer without the mark-up. Could you provide that? And what do you mean by "I am using the "#ActionAddForm" selector, which is probably not loaded"?

Comment: "#ActionAddForm" is the id of the form, sorry for the confusion. I will add some html markup.

Comment: You say that there's multiple forms in multiple tabs, right? And they have different ids?

Comment: actually the same form gets loaded with ajax, but with the same id. hmmm maybe that is the problem. thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't, as long as only one of the is on the page at the time of the click. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID has to be unique, but it sounds like you use the ID vor every form(what will not work, the browser fetches only 1 element - which one depends on the browser).
Try removing the last used form as soon as the new form is loaded.

Or use another selector, something like `form:visible`